# How to get the version of IDA Pro use IDC or IDAPython?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

Because some of the IDC function names are changed in different IDA Pro versions. I want to know how to use IDC or IDAPython to get the current version of IDA Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can check idaapi.IDA_SDK_VERSION. Source: http://www.idabook.com/tools/sdk_versions.h